# Differential equation describing how an object evolves; how to program it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a grid of units whose dynamics are said to be governed by the same differential equation. As I understand it, a differential equation describes how a given function is related to its derivative. In a situation like this, how do I simulate the units? If I know the parameters of each unit, I could solve the differential equation, and there would be nothing to simulate (just compute the function values ..)

Is there something I am missing? Could I, say, just initialize each unit to a random state and then update using the differential equation directly?

Comment: Very broad question. Difficult to answer, it is. Oh no, Yoda level drunk, I am getting.

Comment: I am looking for a briefly described set of ideas of how to proceed. I would be very happy for any answer

Comment: What kind of differential equation? Linear? Nonlinear? Constant parameters? Varying parameters?